# XML in string format to org.w3c.dom.Document in Java

Tags: java, dom, saml

I am trying to convert a samlResponse in string format to org.w3c.dom.Document to validate it. But it yields null even though I have used couple of different ways.
One way is as below:
Here even the inputStream is null.
`BasicParserPool bpp = new BasicParserPool(); 
 bpp.setNamespaceAware(true); 
Document doc= bpp.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(samlResponse.getBytes())); 
 Element responseElement = doc.getDocumentElement();`

where the string samlResponse is as below (just a snippet):

```
String samlResponse = "<saml2p:Response xmlns:saml2p=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol\"  xmlns:xs=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" Version=\"2.0\">   <saml2:Issuer etc etc
```

Any thoughts where I am going wrong?

Comment: what, specifically, is "null"?

Comment: also, don't convert xml strings to bytes in order to parse as you can break the character encoding.  use a StringReader instead.

Answer (score 2):

BasicParserPool is an OpenSAML class, and I haven't used OpenSAML, so I can't say why it isn't working.

I can give you a simple alternative that works for me however.

I convert Strings to org.w3c.dom.Document using javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory and javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
Document result = dbf.newDocumentBuilder().parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes()));
```

where "xml" is the String to convert. There is some exception-catching that I have left out.

The API is here: [DocumentBuilder API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this piece of below code helps

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

/**
 *
 * @author karthikeyan.s1
 */
public class Parser {

    public Document getDomElement(String xml) {
        Document doc = null;
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        dbf.setCoalescing(true);
        dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
        try {

            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            InputSource is = new InputSource();
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
            doc = db.parse(is);
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            // Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            // Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //  Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }

        return doc;
    }
}
```